# Is there a term for the amount of time one devotes to a job, as in full-time, part-time, half-time?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, hypernyms, business-language

This question came up when I was posting job openings on a website and needed to list the various aspects of each position using label/value pairs, like so:

Benefits: Included

Availability: Immediate

_________: Full time

I struggled to fill that blank.  What's a suitable and succinct label for a field that indicates how much of your work day a job occupies?  Time worked?  Work level?  (Perhaps "occupational temporal commitment"? j/k)  Nothing I came up with seemed quite right, so I was curious if anyone knew if there's an accepted term for this.

Comment: How about *Hours Required*?

Comment: Those *are* the terms. The *requirement:* is that they be full time employees.

Comment: *Required hours* then?

Comment: Simply "Work time" or "Working time".

Comment: If the jobs were listed as "40 hours/week", "20 hours/week", etc., then "hours required" would work well.  However, "full time" or "part time" are less exact indications of availability, so labeling them with anything that says "hours" might be a slight mismatch.

Comment: *Hours* seems OK. You may want more detail on when exactly you're expected to work - but changing the label won't help.

Comment: **Why** would it be necessary to put anything in that blank? In a posting of a job opening, one can just say that the job is full-time; there is no reason for a posting to look as if it were a form of some kind.

Answer (score 4):

At my place of work (literally in our job postings), this is called **Schedule**. It covers the gamut of what the expectations are in terms of time commitment for the job, and implies that there is some structure to it.

You could also use **Time Commitment**. I think that would imply that the hours worked are the same week-to-week but the distribution is more fluid.

Answer (score 2):

A reasonable term to use is ***workday***:

> : the period of time in a day during which you work at a job
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/workday)</sub>

Comment: Or working week, since you may have a 9-5 day but only do 3  days a week.

Answer (score 1):

[Dice](https://www.dice.com) lists full/part/etc as ***employment type*** search parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very late to this party, but since no one has proposed it, I'll suggest "status". This is often used to describe the condition of a person's employment as full-time, part-time, temporary, etc. For example:

> Under the look-back measurement method, an employer may determine **the status of an employee as a full-time employee** during . . . ("[Identifying Full-time Employees](https://www.irs.gov/affordable-care-act/employers/identifying-full-time-employees)", U.S. IRS website, updated 29 September 2022)

> Massachusetts does not have a legal definition for full-time or part-time employees. Please see your employee handbook for your employer’s definition of **full-time vs. part-time status**. ("[Massachusetts law about employment](https://www.mass.gov/info-details/massachusetts-law-about-employment)", mass.gov website, updated 22 May 2023)

Comment: Good point, not every state or commonwealth has a definition of FT vs PT; in some it is  defined by the employer.   It would help to know more about the location in question.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with, ***duration***.

> the length of time that something lasts or continues [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/duration)

Comment: Although that could distinguish temporary contract or permanent work.

Answer (score 0):

I work in the Fiscal Office for a medical department at a large American university, and they're always slinging around “FTE” — full time equivalent. This job is 0.75 FTE. Dr. McCoy is working 0.3 FTE in facility X and 0.5 FTE in facility Y.

So instead of X: Full time, you could say “FTE 1.0”. How many of your readers would know what it means is up for grabs. No one else has posted it yet, suggesting to me that it may not be widely used. You could spell it out, space permitting, or define it once at the top. Or your readers could just google it; it comes right up.

Perusing the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-time_equivalent), it appears that it’s mostly used in the U.S. federal government and in universities. No data on which universities outside the U.S. (I see you’re U.S.; this is directed at other readers.)

Answer (score 0):

[Monster](http://jobsearch.monster.com/AdvancedSearch.aspx) uses **job type**: full time, part time, temp, etc.