# What is the field heading for employees where typical values would be "full-time" or "part time"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm making a roster in a spreadsheet of all the current employees, volunteers, sports coaches, and other workers at a school. What is the best way to label the column showing if someone is Full-time, Part-time, Volunteer, or On-call (like substitute teachers)? What word represents this?

I already have a Status field denoting Current vs. Former. Should I just merge this unnamed field so that Current becomes more precise as Full-time/Part-time and then Former? It's in the same logical realm, I think.

Comment: _What word represents..._ seems to be missing an ending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug a little deeper and found this post from 7 years, 7 months ago.

[Is there a term for the amount of time one devotes to a job, as in full-time, part-time, half-time?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/289714/is-there-a-term-for-the-amount-of-time-one-devotes-to-a-job-as-in-full-time-pa)

The top answer was: **Schedule**.

Comment: Are you happy to accept that as an answer to your question?